# Facebook API, "app/scores" is deprecated what are the alternatives? (Facebook SDK v3.1, Unity 2018.1.0f)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to get Facebook Integration for a Unity Game I am working on. I can Login fine. But I have now found out that the old scores option has been depreciated in this version of the Facebook SDK.

What are my alternatives now?

I need to be able to have an array of scores from 3 game modes saved and then be able to compare them against the friends list of the player using facebook.

I've tried looking around but I'm not sure what to do now.

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Facebook has removed this feature. The alternative is that you build your own scoring system (which will likely require a server-side component.)